# How to find a pattern inside a pattern when start and end is known?

Tags: python, nlp, python-re

I have a pattern that has a starting and ending pattern like:

```
start = '\n\\[\n'
end = '\n\\]\n'
```

My string is:

```
'The above mentioned formal formula is\nthat of\n\\[\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)\n\\]\nA. Tobacco\nB. Tulip\nc. soybean\nD. Sunhemp'
```

I want to find:

```
\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)'
```

If I use:

```
re.findall(r'\s*\\+\n\\[\n(.*?)\\+\n\\]\n', mystring)

r'\s*\\+\[(.*?)\\+\]' # did not work either
```

then it gives me an empty result. What am  I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
mystring = 'The above mentioned formal formula is\nthat of\n\\[\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)\n\\]\nA. Tobacco\nB. Tulip\nc. soybean\nD. Sunhemp'

expected_result = '\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)'

import codecs
import re

matches = re.findall(r'\\n\\\\\[(\\n.*)\\n\\\\\]\\n', repr(mystring))

results = [codecs.decode(match, 'unicode_escape') for match in matches]

results
['\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)']

results[0] == expected_result
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = '\n\\'
end = '\n\\]\n'


s = 'The above mentioned formal formula is\nthat of\n\\[\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)\n\\]\nA. Tobacco\nB. Tulip\nc. soybean\nD. Sunhemp'
test_str = "\n\\oplus \\bigoplus_{(5)} \\widehat{C_{(5)}} A_{5} G(2)"


idx_start = s.find(start) + len(start) + 1
idx_end = s.rfind(end)


found = s[idx_start:idx_end]
found == test_str

OUTPUT:
True
```

Comment: Any idea on *RE*?